# I want to make it appear again on the checkbox click but doesn't work

Tags: jquery

```
$('.98').click(function() {
      if ($('.98').not(":checked"))
      {
           $('.flat-table tr').each(function() {
                var row = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
                if (row == "98" && $(this).is(":visible")) {
                     $(this).hide();
                }
           });
      }else{
           $('.flat-table tr').each(function() {
                var row = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
                if (row == "98") {
                     $(this).show();
                }
           });
      }
 });
```

This is the code, the checkbox has **98** class and is checked at the beginning. When I check it off, it disappears. But once I click it back in it doesn't appear back. Any solutions or tips on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.98').click(function() {
      $('.flat-table tr').each(function() {
           var row = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
           if (row == "98" && $(this).is(":visible")) {
                $(this).hide();
           }else if(row == "98" && $(this).is(":hidden")){
                $(this).show();
           }
      });
 });
```

Figured it out!

So how I came to that is first, I don't need to check that it is not checked because we only bind the click function to .98 so no need to double-check that. Lastly, it looked too complicated so I tried to rework it. and instead, check if the row that contains 98 is true and if it is visible then hide it. Now next time you click it won't active since it is :hidden. So just go for else if and check for the same text but now instead of visible. Check for hidden ;) that is how I solved it!

Comment: Well done! But, in order to help those who follow you and need to try and understand your solution, could you explain how your answer solves the problem you asked about?

Comment: Sure, I will edit my answer!